# Difference between STRPOS and POSITION in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

***Beginner here.***

Is there any other difference apart from syntax in **position and strpos function**?

If not then why do we have two functions which can achieve the same thing just with a bit of syntax difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those functions do the exactly same thing and differ only in syntax. Documentation for `strpos()` says:

> Location of specified substring (same as position(substring in string), but note the
>   reversed argument order)

Reason why they both exist and differ only in syntax is that `POSITION(str1 IN str2)` is defined by ANSI SQL standard. If PostgreSQL had only `strpos()` it wouldn't be able to run ANSI SQL queries and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both commands in order to reach the same goal, i.e. finding the location of a substring in a given string. However, they have different syntaxes and order of arguments:

```
strpos(String, Substring);
position(Substring in String);
```

[image]

Take a look at all string functions and operators of PostgreSQL [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)